# How to find in server side if user clicked yes in client side popup

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, client-side, server-side

I am adding an event on server side button click:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "openPopUp", "javascript:onClick();", true);
```

and in client side I have a function:

```
function onClick() {

    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to go ahead ?.");

    if (r == true) {
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I find in server-side if user has clicked yes or no ?

Comment: ajax. By the time client side script is running the all the server side code is completely done.

Comment: Are you wanting to do a full post back after the click or just execute a method via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Add a HiddenField to the page and retrieve the value afterwards.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidResultOfConfirm" />
```

Javascript:

```
function onClick() {

    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to go ahead ?.");

    if (r == true) {
        document.getElementById('<%=hidResultOfConfirm.ClientID%>').value = "true";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%=hidResultOfConfirm.ClientID%>').value = "false";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then on the server side just check `hidResultOfConfirm.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not find out on the server. Learn about the page life cycle. JavaScript runs after the page is loaded, the server has completely finished loading.

If you need to get user input, you need to look into posting back the page again or making an Ajax call.